# Request.put method gets 500 response when using data={...} argument, and 200 response when using json={...} argument instead. Why?

Tags: rest, api, python-requests

```
res = requests.put(url=self.URL, json=self.output) # gives <Response [200]>
res = requests.put(url=self.URL, data=self.output) # gives <Response [500]>
```

This is an example of the dictionary I am trying to upload:

```
{u'RPT6': '22,4', u'RPT7': '13,2', u'RPT4': '4,1', u'RPT5': '13,1', u'RPT2': '18,4', u'RPT3': '7,1', u'RPT1': '1,1', 'Last Change Time': '2017/09/19 - 16:24:28', u'RPT8': '5,1', u'RPT9': '10,3', '
Last Change Author': 'CNBCN477QB', u'RPT10': '22,4', u'RPT11': '22,3', u'RPT12': '15,3'}
```

This dictonary is a modification of an original json file obtained from the same url `www.myjson.com` using `requests.get` method. Therefore I understand there is no problem with the server. After cheaking [the related documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.put) I am not able to discover why I get that error as it is clearly stated that the use of a dictionary goes with the `data` argument.

Comment: Is it really a Dictionary or only a Json-string representing it?

Comment: It is certainly a python dictionary.

Comment: Which Rest-API are you targeting? Maybe it can't handle form-encoded body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the `data` parameter will urlencode your data and create a 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' Content-Type header, while the `json` parameter will send json formated data and a 'application/json' Content-Type header.

Let's see what the server recieves using the `data` parameter:

```
data = {'key 1':'a string', 'key 2': 2, 'key 3':True}
res = requests.put('http://somesite.com', data=data)

print(res.request.method + ' / HTTP/1.1')
print('\r\n'.join(': '.join(i) for i in res.request.headers.items()))
print()
print(res.request.body)
```

> PUT / HTTP/1.1
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>   Accept: */*
>   User-Agent: python-requests/2.18.1
>   Content-Length: 33
>   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> key+1=a+string&key+2=2&key+3=True

---

Now let's send the same data with the `json` parameter:

```
data = {'key 1':'a string', 'key 2': 2, 'key 3':True}
res = requests.put('http://somesite.com', json=data)

print(res.request.method + ' / HTTP/1.1')
print('\r\n'.join(': '.join(i) for i in res.request.headers.items()))
print()
print(res.request.body)
```

> PUT / HTTP/1.1
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>   Accept: */*
>   User-Agent: python-requests/2.18.1
>   Content-Length: 48
>   Content-Type: application/json
>
> {"key 1": "a string", "key 2": 2, "key 3": true}

As you can see the two HTTP requests are very different.